# Sphinx / rST: using configuration values in include statements?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

In my main sphinx project I am using `include` statements to pull content of files that are stored in another place on my disk.

```
.. include:: //path/to/other/docs/file.rst
```

Now I want to be able to set the base path in my `conf.py` once, and simply reference this in my include statements.

Is this possible and if so, how can I achieve this?

---

For future reference: I wrote a Sphinx extension that allows this, see:
https://github.com/j0nes2k/sphinx-contrib-configurableinclude

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that with vanilla Sphinx. An implementation of `include` directive seems to does not care any additional configuration option:

- [`sphinx.directives.other.Include.run()`](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/c1255774ae7c43781bf49a80e7aef4606ffe14e0/sphinx/directives/other.py?at=default#cl-387)
- [`sphinx.environment.BuildEnvironment.relfn2path()`](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/c1255774ae7c43781bf49a80e7aef4606ffe14e0/sphinx/environment.py?at=default#cl-312)

But you can implement and setup your own directive. Check out [*Writing a simple extension*](http://sphinx-doc.org/extdev/tutorial.html#tutorial-writing-a-simple-extension) section of [*Developing extensions for Sphinx*](http://sphinx-doc.org/extdev/index.html).

So the easiest way seems to overrides `sphinx.directives.other.Include`. (Actually, Sphinx's `Include` also overrode the standard include directive `docutils.parsers.rst.directives.misc.Include` for better and correct path interpreting.)

Comment: Thanks! I have implemented a first working version of this extension. I can configure include paths, and the file gets written to my document. However the file is inserted "as is", the rST markup like titles etc are not evaluated or parsed. What am I missing? Example so far: https://gist.github.com/j0nes2k/8672186

Comment: @j0nes Actually I never implemented sphinx extension so I can't figure out where is the problem, just got suspicious about `nodes.Text`. And I fixed my answer just now so check it out again, plz. `LiteralInclude` stands for the *literal* and there was another `Include`. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks! For future reference, here is the extension I wrote:
https://github.com/j0nes2k/sphinx-contrib-configurableinclude